# Android Environment Variable

Tags: android, build, continuous-integration, environment

I'm developing an Android app that makes api calls to a remote server. When I'm developing, I point to my local server. Furthermore, I also have an continuous integration server that has the web app running locally too. How can I manage to configure the different urls so everytime I commit to CI server, I don't need to change the url before. I tried localhost but it doesn't work since localhost is the emulator itself.

edit 1: I managed to find that 10.0.2.2 points to my machine localhost but that only works on emulators. Any solution for real devices?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could address is to have a separate config file with flag in your code which indicates whether your app is in local mode, or has been built from the CI server. This file is by default always set to 'CI server mode' and you locally over-ride it ( but never really check-in this file ).

All your service calls, can be split it into two parts. One part would be the end-point and the other part would be the actual actions / operations on those end-points.

ONE BIG URL = 'END-POINT' + REST OF THE URL

Once you have done this split, all you need to do is to modify the first part of this split URL depending upon the value of the flag which I described previously.